# выборка по временному интервалу, заданному в сек

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно получить все записи за последние 30 дней (в бд время заданно как date bigint(20) и записывается туда через time())
Запрос:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `product` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '".time()-30."' AND '".time()."'
```

Ничего не выдает хоть в интервале есть поля для выборки

Comment: функция fromunixtime

Comment: поменял на `SELECT `id` FROM `product` WHERE `date` BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(".time()-30.")
                                                                                AND FROM_UNIXTIME(".time().")` чёт то же самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вычитаете вы 30 **секунд**, а не дней.
[time()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) возвращает секунды.

Можно сделать так:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `product` WHERE `date` > '".(time() - 30 * 24 * 3600)."'
```

Или обойтись без time() и воспользоваться UNIX_TIMESTAMP():

```
SELECT `id` FROM `product` WHERE `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 30 * 24 * 3600
```

Comment: С интервалами работать гораздо приятнее: `select id from product where date > now()-interval 30 day`